# How can I apply a decorator to an imported function?

Tags: python, function, decorator, python-decorators

Suppose I have imported a function:

```
from random import randint
```

and then want to apply a decorator to it. Is there some syntactic sugar for this, perhaps something like so?

```
@decorator
randint
```

Or do I have create a wrapper function to decorate, like so?

```
@decorator
def randintWrapper(*args):
    return random.randint(*args)
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Decorators are just syntactic sugar to replace a function object with a decorated version, where *decorating* is just *calling* (passing in the original function object). In other words, the syntax:

```
@decorator_expression
def function_name():
    # function body
```

roughly<sup>(*)</sup> translates to:

```
def function_name():
    # function body
function_name = decorator_expression(function_name)
```

In your case, you can apply your decorator manually instead:

```
from random import randint

randint = decorator(randint)
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> When using `@<decorator>` on a function or class, the result of the `def` or `class` definition is not bound (assigned to their name in the current namespace) first. The decorator is passed the object directly from the stack, and only the result of the decorator call is then bound.

Comment: The only problem is that the docstring and method name is not preserved. Maybe want to use `functools.wraps`

Comment: @pratikm: that's a separate issue though. The decorator should indeed use `functools.wraps`, but that doesn't change how can you *apply* the decorator.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for flask route decorators. That is `@app.route('/route', methods=['GET'])`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: it works jut fine for Flask route decorators, provided you call the result of the decorator factory: `app.route('/route', methods=['GET'])(view_func)` (no need to capture the return value, since the `app.route()` decorator registers, and returns the view function unaltered). Not that you should do that however, since you could just use [`app.add_url_rule()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) instead: `app.add_url_rule('/route', view_func.__name__, view_func, methods=['GET'])`.

Comment: The clearest example I have seen so far. Note that your decorator itself may be a called function rather than the function name. E.g. I had to do `torch.cuda.amp.autocast()(model.forward)` It is weird because there are 2 parentheses next to each other, but that is the consequence of being a programmer.

Comment: @CoreyLevinson the term for those is a decorator *factory*. Like the Flask `route` decorator factory, it’s the call that returns the actual decorator. This is generally used to configure the decorator that’s being produced. E.g. `autocast()` takes an `enabled` parameter.