# How to document Python functions with overload/dispatch decorators?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, python-decorators, dispatch

## Applying Documentation to Multi-Dispatched Functions

I am using the [`multipledispatch`](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch/blob/master/docs/source/design.rst) package, in a fashion similar to the example code below.  I want to be able to see the `docstring` text when I ask for `help(my_add)` in the Python command line, but instead all I see is information about the decorator.

### `Functools.wraps` must be the way to do it, but how?

I have looked up [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), which I'm sure is what I want to use.  I have found examples of how to use it, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829364/applying-a-decorator-to-an-imported-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-handling-docstrings).

But I still don't entirely understand two issues:

1. How to apply the `functools.wraps` to external decorators that I don't "own".
2. How to apply it specifically to this case with multiple dispatch, since the function I want to wrap will have multiple `docstrings` associated with the same function name.

## Example: Decorated Function Creation

Below is an example to help explain.

```
>>> from multipledispatch import dispatch
>>> @dispatch(str, str)
... def my_add(elem1, elem2):
...   '''A flavor of 'add' where two strings are concatenated.'''
...   return elem1 + ' ' + elem2
... 
>>> @dispatch(int, int)
... def my_add(elem1, elem2):
...   '''A flavor of 'my_add' where two strings are concatenated.'''
...   return elem1 + elem2
... 
>>> my_add('hey','you')
'hey you'
>>> my_add(4, 5)
9
>>> my_add(4.5, 6)
```

(Traceback details removed...)

```
KeyError: (<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
NotImplementedError: Could not find signature for my_add: <float, int>
```

I wanted to show that error and the different dispatches just to show that that part is working as I want it (looking for the matched dispatch and calling the associated "flavor" of the function).

## Example: Calling `help` on the Decorated Function Fails!

But next, if I try to look at the help, instead of seeing the simple `docstring` that I have provided, I see the docstring associated with the `@dispatch` decorator.

```
>>> help(my_add)

Help on Dispatcher in module multipledispatch.dispatcher object:

my_add = class Dispatcher(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 |      Call self as a function.
 |  
 |  __getstate__(self)
 |
```

etc.

---

I'm not even sure what it **should** show, since there are ***potentially 2 conflicting docstrings*** I'd like to push forward.  So, I tried to see if I could call help on a function that's actually run, but then of course it gives me help on the returned data type.  E.g.,

```
>>> help(my_add(3, 5))

Help on int object:

class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `functools.wraps()` decorator would have to be part of the *decorator implementation* and you can't apply it after the fact. The issue here is that the decorator returns an instance of a custom class, and `help()` can only show documentation for the *class* of that instance.

The `Dispatcher()` instance the decorator returns **already has a `__doc__` attribute**, one which lists the doc strings of all decorated functions. From the documentation you linked:

> The `Dispatcher` creates a detailed docstring automatically. To add a description of the multimethod itself, provide it when creating the `Dispatcher`.

The docstring is there for your example too:

```
>>> print(my_add.__doc__)
Multiply dispatched method: my_add

Inputs: <str, str>
-------------------
A flavor of 'add' where two strings are concatenated.

Inputs: <int, int>
-------------------
A flavor of 'my_add' where two strings are concatenated.
```

(note that the docstrings are reflected correctly from your example, complete with errors).

The real issue here is that `help()` can only print the `__doc__` string of the *class*, so `print(type(my_add).__doc__))` is used as a starting point. This is not something that can easily be changed; just stick to printing the `__doc__` attribute of the instance directly.

Comment: Wow!  I didn't think the solution would be that easy!  Thank you very much, Martijn!  It's interesting that `.__doc__` can be changed but that `help` cannot easily point to it.  I think understand what you're saying, regarding the class.  But I don't quite understand how that works.  I always thought that `my_add.__doc__` was **exactly** the same as `help(my_add)`, just syntactic sugar.  I guess you're saying that `my_add.__doc__` can be overwritten to point to the *function* `my_add`, but that `help(my_add)` is still actually pointing to `help(dispatch)` and cannot be changed.  Is that right?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson: What would `help(1)` produce, or `help('some string')`? `help()` gives you information on what you can do with the *type* of the argument. So yes, `help(my_add)` will give you help on the `Dispatch` class, not the specific instance of that class. By extension, that means the `__doc__` of the instance is not used.