# How to apply a decorator with arguments to an imported function

Tags: import, decorator

This similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829364/applying-a-decorator-to-an-imported-function) but not quite.

Like the other question, I want to apply a decorator to an imported function, but in my case, my decorator requires arguments

Working

```py
from flask_restx import Namespace
from . import exceptions as e

api = Namespace('v2', 'API Version 2' )

@api.errorhandler(e.MissingPrompt)
def handle_bad_requests(error):
    '''Namespace error handler'''
    logger.warning(error.log)
    return({'message': error.specific}, error.code)
```

But I want to move handle_bad_requests() to its own file

so I want it like

```py
from flask_restx import Namespace
from . import exceptions as e

api = Namespace('v2', 'API Version 2' )

@api.errorhandler(e.MissingPrompt)
e.handle_bad_requests # ??
```

I tried like the other answers here suggested like this

```py
handle_bad_requests  = api.errorhandler(e.handle_bad_requests, e.MissingPrompt)
```

But that just gives me an error I am sending too many arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the answer nested within the comments of a previous answer

```py
handle_bad_requests = api.errorhandler(e.MissingPrompt)(e.handle_bad_requests)
```

And that seems to work fine.

The double parentheses would never have occured to me